# UWP Windows.Media.Playback - Stop/Unload Clip

Tags: c#, uwp, media-player

I'm writing a UWP application which contains the MediaPlayer object. I am wanting to program a stop button which stops the media and sets the media to black however I can't find an approach to do it short of loading a short 'black' clip as an internal asset or hiding the element via the compositor.

The MediaPlayer does not have a function for stop, only play/pause and further, setting the media source to null simply pauses playback and freezes on the last frame shown rather than dropping to black.

Any suggestions would be much appreciated.

Comment: Any updates? Have it resolved?

Comment: I have tried using MediaPlayerElement as you suggested but it also doesn't drop to black, instead it rewinds to the first frame of the video and holds there. The reason I was wanted a drop to black was that I was hiding a layer on top of the video (such as ajpeg) when a new video starts. The media player object appears to have a few niggles which I'm trying to get around where it reports that it has started playing the new video file (so I then hide the jpeg layer based on that event) but I still get a flash of the old video file before the new one displays

Comment: I suggested using MediaElement  not a MediaPlayerElement. Please check my reply.

Comment: Sorry, I wrote MediaPlayerElement rather than MediaElement above. The findings above are based on your suggestion.

Answer (score 2):

I recently had a related problem that boiled down to unloading media from a [`MediaPlayerElement`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.mediaplayerelement.aspx).

If you navigate away from a page when playback is active, the [`MediaPlayerElement`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.mediaplayerelement.aspx) would not suspend or unload a playback in progress so the user would keep hearing the audio. If you re-open player's page, a new instance of a player control will be created and user may hear multiple audio tracks at once (although this requires different media sources). So it was essential to unload the media at some place like player's [`Unloaded`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.frameworkelement#Windows_UI_Xaml_FrameworkElement_Unloaded) event handler, page `Unloaded` handler, or [`OnNavigatingFrom`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.page)/[`OnNavigatedFrom`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.page) overrides.

Anyway, the code below stops and unloads a video/clip/media from the [`MediaPlayerElement`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.mediaplayerelement.aspx).

```
MyMediaPlayerElement.MediaPlayer.Pause();
MyMediaPlayerElement.Source = null;
```

Actually, a null assignment line works just fine as a stop-and-unload, but since as of now (3/19/2018), MS documentation doesn't seem to cover how nullifying the source supposed to work, I prefer to keep an otherwise unnecessary call to Pause() here as well.

Answer (score -1):

> The MediaPlayer does not have a function for stop, only play/pause

As you known, [`MediaPlayerElement`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.mediaplayerelement.aspx) doesn't have stop method at default. Since `MediaPlayerElement` is newly for version 1607, for earlier version of Windows 10 we use `MediaElement` instead, so you can simply use [`MediaElement`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.mediaelement.aspx) instead. `MediaElement` has [`Stop`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.mediaelement.stop.aspx) method, and after you invoke the stop method, the `MediaElement` will show black and set the media to begin which is just what you want. Code as follows:

```
 <MediaElement x:Name="mediaelement" AreTransportControlsEnabled="True" Height="400" Width="400" AutoPlay="True" Source="http://distribution.bbb3d.renderfarming.net/video/mp4/bbb_sunflower_1080p_30fps_normal.mp4"></MediaElement>
 <Button x:Name="btnstop" Click='btnstop_Click' Content="stop"></Button>
```

Code behind:

```
private void btnstop_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    mediaelement.Stop();             
}
```